# JavaScript's get-it-done nature

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is JavaScript intended to be running as little as possible on a website/webapp? By that I mean is the usual intention to run through all your js files as soon as the page loads and put them aside, and then when functions come up to execute them right away and be done with it?

I'm working on a project using google maps and I have a custom marker object scripted out, and a debugger has told me that the browser runs through all my js files before anything even appears on the page.

My problem comes in here: I wanted to animate certain markers to bounce up and down continuously with jQuery (similar to OS X icons in the dock) and my several attempts at infinite loop functions all just crash the browser. So I understand that the browser doesn't like that, **but is there a way to have a simple script be repeating itself in the background while the user navigates the page?** Or is JavaScript just not supposed to be used that way?

(I worked with Flash for a long time so my mindset is still there.)

Comment: So, in other words, "how can I schedule repeating tasks in Javascript"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Javascript functions should just do their bit and exit as soon as possible. The GUI and the scripts run on the same single thread, so as long as you are inside a Javascript function, nothing shows up in the browser. If you try to use an infinite loop, the browser will appear to freeze.

You use the `window.setInterval` and `window.setTimeout` methods to trigger code that runs at a specific time. By running an interval that updates something several times a second, you can create an animation.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set a timer to execute a script after a defined time.

```
var timer = setTimeout(code, milliseconds);
```

will execute `code` in so-and-so milliseconds. Each execution of the script can set a new timer to execute the script again.

You can cancel a timed event using `clearTimeout(timer)`.

Comment: I actually had trouble with `setTimeout` my js would just skip over `setTimeout`'d lines and kept going, and never get around to doing what it was supposed to in 2000 milliseconds or whatever. I think there are complications that come with using Google maps

Answer (score 1):

Use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) or [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval). The MDC articles on it are pretty good.

You'll need to update inside of functions that run quickly, but get called many times, instead of updating inside of a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said that you are using jQuery, consider using its [effects API](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) (e.g., `jQuery.animate()`), it will make your life much easier!

Comment: Yes I love `animate()` but my problem was with the timing and looping of the animation rather than how to create the animation itself.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I save as much code as possible for execution after the page has loaded, partly by putting all my `<script>`s at the bottom of `<body>`. This means a (perceived) reduction in page load time, whilst having all my JS ready to run when need be.

I wouldn't recommend going through everything you need to do at the beginning of the document. Instead, bind things to events such as clicks of buttons, etc.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, and things will probably work a little differently when I'm pulling from a database, but Google maps requires a lot of js to run `onload()`.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, whoever that was. The Silent Ninjas of Downvote have struck again. Anyway, maybe put Google's script at the end of `<body>`. It should help things a bit.

Comment: Maybe they disagree with your strategy? Thanks I'll poke that with a stick

Comment: That's true. Still, I'd appreciate a comment as to _why_ they downvoted, but I digress. Glad I could be of some help.

Comment: Maybe the downvote originates to the fact that your answer does not answer the question at all.